# How can I reactivate my Twitter account?

Tags: twitter, account-management

I deactivated my Twitter account around 20 days back, and I want to reactivate the same account, but I can't.

Twitter asks me to recheck my password and username but it's perfectly correct. I tried the 'forgot password' as well, but i didn't receive a mail yet.

Comment: Please don't add tags that don't belong on the question.  `security` I could see, but `google-apps` was just plain incorrect.

Comment: Contact Twitter support.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [contact Twitter support here](https://support.twitter.com/forms/restore).

I found this link on this page:
"[I'm having trouble reactivating my account](https://support.twitter.com//forums/10713-troubleshooting/entries/16807-i-can-t-restore-my-account)"